# TeeChart ScrolllPager Tool

Tags: activex, teechart

I want to implement Scroll Pager Tool in my code. But not Getting this tool detail in EToolClass. Can anyone let me know how this tool can be implemented with TeeChart201464.ocx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is already present in the public tracker:
http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=588

Comment: Hi Yeray, thanks for update till when can we expect the Release since we have to provide the release to our client ASAP.

Comment: It has a high priority but I can't tell you when it will be closed. I'd suggest you to add your mail to the CC list to be automatically notified when an update arrives.

Comment: Is this issue fixed in the latest TChart ActiveX control.

Comment: As you can see in the link to the ticket, I'm afraid it hasn't been closed yet.